# Make an object a "character buffer object"

Tags: python, object

I have a custom class, which has some string data. I wish to be able to save this string data to a file, using a file handle's write object. I have implemented `__str__()`, so i can do `str(myobject)`, what is the equivalent method for making python consider my object to be a character buffer object?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do: `fileObject.write(str(myobject))` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "character buffer object". Do you mean you want Python to treat your object as a file object? http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: Only that write()ing this kind of object is a common use case, and it seems verbose.

@dpitch40 - TypeError: expected a character buffer object when doing open('filename.ext','w').write(myobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use your object with library code, that expects to be able to write what you give it to a file, then you may have to resort to implementing a "duck file" class that acts like a `file` but supports your stringable object.  Unfortunately, `file` is not a type that you can subclass easily, at least as of Python 2.6.  You will have to implement enough of the file protocol (`write`, `writelines`, `tell`, etc.) to allow the library code to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, str() isn't so bad after all then.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single function, but a whole range of them - `read`, `seek`, etc.

Why don't you subclass `StringIO.StringIO`, which is already a string buffer?

Comment: Maybe I worded my question poorly, I wish to write my custom object to standard files, using standard file handlers.

Comment: Then maybe it's actually `file` you want to subclass.  That's a strange notion, though, are you sure you really have 'a file'?